# SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY method 13349 Error

Tags: java, oracle, geometry, spatial, jts

I am using **jts geometry** object to store my geometry objects as an Oracle **SDO_Geometry**. My geometries in WGS84 coordinates. Even I created a spatial index still have some problems when I try to validate my geometry with SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY method **I got 13349 Error**.I guess my create circle method is not working correctly. Even I set SRID no for WGS84 , it calculates wrong points for the circle. Couldn't find a solution. Do you know where is the problem?

And here is the code that I call the createCircle method

> Geometry area;
>
> area=createCircle(lon, lat, range);
>
> area.setSRID(4326);

```
private static Geometry createCircle(double x, double y, final double RADIUS)
{
    GeometricShapeFactory shapeFactory = new GeometricShapeFactory();
    shapeFactory.setCentre(new Coordinate(x, y));
    shapeFactory.setSize(RADIUS * 2);
    return shapeFactory.createCircle();
}
```

Comment: Can you try using SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT?

Comment: I have just tried it still get the " 13349 [Element <1>] [Ring <1>][Edge <16>][Edge <59>] "  same error.

Answer (score 0):

The number you get is an Oracle error number. Search for ORA-13349 and you will get a better idea of what is wrong with the geometry.

ORA-13349: polygon boundary crosses itself

Comment: Is there  a list of possible error number for `SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY` or I have to google each one?